# Create logon token using BI Platform RESTful SDK

Tags: rest, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm attempting to create a logon token using the BOE BI Platform RESTful SDK v4.1 (using [RESTClient](http://www.restclient.net/)).

A GET request to `http://server:6405/biprws/logon/long/` returns:

```
<attrs xmlns="http://www.sap.com/rws/bip">
  <attr name="userName" type="string" /> 
  <attr name="password" type="string" /> 
  <attr name="auth" type="string" possibilities="secEnterprise,secLDAP,secWinAD,secSAPR3">secEnterprise</attr> 
</attrs>
```

A `POST` to `http://server:6405/biprws/logon/long/` with a single header of `Content-Type: application/xml` and a payload of

```
<attrs xmlns="http://www.sap.com/rws/bip">
  <attr name="userName" type="string">myAccount</attr>
  <attr name="password" type="string">myPassword</attr>
  <attr name="auth" type="string" possibilities="secEnterprise,secLDAP,secWinAD,secSAPR3">secWinAD</attr>
</attrs>
```

returns:

```
<error>
    <error_code>FWM 00006</error_code>
    <message>Active Directory Authentication failed to log you on. Please contact your system administrator to make sure you are a member of a valid mapped group and try again. If you are not a member of the default domain, enter your user name as UserName@DNS_DomainName, and then try again. (FWM 00006)</message>
</error>
```

I've also tried `attr name="userName" type="string">myAccount@mycompany.org</attr>`, but with the same results.

A `POST` to `http://server:6405/biprws/logon/adsso` returns:

```
<error>
  <error_code>RWS 00057</error_code>
  <message>Method not allowed (RWS 00057)</message>
</error>
```

The credentials work with BI Launchpad and the CMC.

What am I missing?

Comment: Relevant: [Business Intelligence Platform RESTful 
Web Service Developer Guide](https://techwriter79.wikispaces.com/file/view/sbo41sp5_bip_rest_ws_en.pdf)

Comment: Do you have WinAD SSO working in BI launch pad?

Comment: You can use Windows AD authentication, but SSO doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

First, a disclaimer -- I've only done REST WinAD with SSO, not manual logon.  So I can't be absolutely sure that my suggestions below will fix your problem.

The call to /biprws/logon/adsso requires a GET not a POST, but that will likely not work until you have SSO working.

There are a few settings that are required for WACS to use WinAD, with or without SSO.  The file is here:
SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\pjs\services\RestWebService\biprws\WEB-INF\web.xml

You will see a section commented out, starting with:

```
<!--  Kerberos filter section starts
```

Uncomment this section.  Then set the following parameters:

- idm.realm
- idm.princ
- idm.keytab
- idm.kdc
- idm.allowUnsecured

The values for these parameters should equal what was set in your system for BI launch pad.  This is in:

```
SAP BusinessObjects\tomcat\webapps\BOE\WEB-INF\config\custom\global.properties
```

The format of the file is different (global.properties is a simple properties file, but web.xml is xml).  So you can't just copy/paste the section, but you can copy the individual values.  For example, in global.properties, you might see:

```
idm.keytab=C:/WINDOWS/bosso.keytab
```

This would be done in web.xml as:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>idm.keytab</param-name>
  <param-value>C:/WINDOWS/bosso.keytab</param-value>
  <description>
      The file containing the keytab that Kerberos will use for 
      user-to-service authentication. If unspecified, SSO will default 
      to using an in-memory keytab with a password specified in the 
      com.wedgetail.idm.sso.password environment variable.
  </description>
</init-param>
```

Couple of references:
http://myinsightbi.blogspot.com/
https://techwriter79.wikispaces.com/file/view/sbo41sp5_bip_rest_ws_en.pdf